# Create a Star Pattern which has 4 random patterns and can random size too

Tags: c#

how to create a method draw(int min_size,int max_size) which a output from method has a detail like this
a. It has a 4 pictures which random size between min_size and max_size
b. That 4 pictures may has a same pattern or not. It up to a random pattern form that 4 pictures and it can up size ratio form random size's input
this's a Pattern
Size = 1

```
* * * * *       * * * * *       * * *   *   * * * * *
*       *       *       *       *   *   *   *       *
*   * * *       * * *   *       *   *   *   *   *   *
*                       *       *       *   *   *   *
* * * * *       * * * * *       * * * * *   *   * * *

pattern A       Pattern B       Pattern C   Pattern D
```

**Now I just can create a Pattern but I don't know how random size form a output. This's my code**

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int minSize = 1;
        int maxSize = 1;

        

        DrawRandomPatterns(minSize, maxSize);
    }

    static void DrawRandomPatterns(int minSize, int maxSize)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int size = random.Next(minSize, maxSize + 1);
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Pattern " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    DrawPatternA(size);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Pattern " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    DrawPatternB(size);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Pattern " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    DrawPatternC(size);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Pattern " + (i + 1) + ":");
                    DrawPatternD(size);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    static void DrawPatternA(int size)
    {
        char[,] pattern = new char[5, 5]
        {
            { '*', '*', '*', '*', '*' },
            { '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*' },
            { '*', ' ', '*', '*', '*' },
            { '*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { '*', '*', '*', '*', '*' }
        };

        // Display the pattern
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(pattern[row, col]);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void DrawPatternB(int size)
    {

        for (int length = 0; length < size; length++)
        {
            for (int height = 0; height < size; height++)
            {
                if ((length == 0 || length == size - 1 || length == size / 1) && height < size - 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("* ");
                }
                else if (height == 0 && length < size - 1) //แนวตังซ้ายสุด
                {
                    Console.Write("* ");
                }
                else if (length == 2 && (height == 2 )) //แนวนอนจุดขวาสุด
                {
                    Console.Write(" * * *");
                }
                else if (height == 3 && length < size - 3) //แนวตังซ้ายสุด
                {
                    Console.Write("    *");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }


    static void DrawPatternC(int size)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
            {
                if ((row == 0 || row == size - 1 || row == size / 2) && col < size - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else if (col == 0 && row < size - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void DrawPatternD(int size)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
            {
                if ((row == 0 || row == size - 1 || row == size / 2) && col < size - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else if (col == 0 && row < size - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to random size with a same ratio

Comment: I will give you a hit, you need to use a direction for each of the patterns you are using while you iterate over it, you want to know that you are moving for example east and you want to print 6 stars, then you do. Now the other patterns are a rotation or  a mirror of the actual one, so maybe you want to add those values on a dimensional array int[,] and print the values from there and also rotate/mirror(reverse) the values when you want to create a random one, but you just need to implement one of them